# Label text characters are not in straight line

Tags: python, kivy

I will try my best to explain the issue I am facing with my kivy app. After I set the text for the Label, it's texture shows scrambled characters. Some characters are up and others are down. You may take a look at the image attached to have a better understanding of the issue. I hope I could explain the problem.[Scrambled characters in kivy Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p89fz.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a "bad" font for your label. Here is how you can change it:

```
Label:
    text: "your text"
    font_name: 'Arial.ttf'
```

For more information include the code :)